# how to solve the issue with apache pdfbox-app jar

Tags: java, apache, jar

I'm working with `pdfbox-app` jar in the current development project.
What I notice was they have removed the `PDPageable` class after `“pdfbox-app-2.0.0-20140226.103319-176.jar` release. because of that I'm getting a compilation error in `setPageable()` method.
I like to know the alternative suggestion for this.

As my know they have removed the `PDPageable` class after `“pdfbox-app-2.0.0-20140226.103319-176.jar` this release.

I know is not stable to use the snapshots for the development. But i like to give a release with the latest pdfbox-app jar. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The best is to download the 2.0 sources with svn 
https://pdfbox.apache.org/downloads.html#scm
and look at the examples. The printing has been changed recently to be more flexible. Search for PDFPrinter and its uses, e.g. in PDFReader.java:

```
                    PDFPrinter printer = new PDFPrinter(document);
                    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
                    job.setPageable(printer.getPageable());
                    if (job.printDialog())
                    {
                        job.print();
                    }
```

Note that PDFPrinter has many new cool constructors to allow more flexibility when printing.

Comment: setPageable() is removed from the latest snapshots.

Comment: Either use the new constructors, or extend PDFPrinter and override getPageable(). If this doesn't help, please include the source of what you were trying to do in the question.

Comment: Any ideas why the latest snapshot (pdfbox-2.0.0-20150107.030113-905.jar) prints the PDF with very large margins (same PDF printed fine with 1.6.0)

Comment: Found the reason: had to use another more complete constructor PDFPrinter printer=new PDFPrinter(doc, Scaling.ACTUAL_SIZE, Orientation.AUTO);