# PDFBOX printing issue: Printed PDF unexpectedly rotated 90 degrees and incorrect size

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT to print the PDF in printer(both HW & virtual), and it printing work but printed PDF unexpectedly rotated 90 degrees and incorrect size.

[example PDF download link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33134610/testPrintPDF/examplePDF.pdf)

[printed result PDF download link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33134610/testPrintPDF/printedPDF%20by%20latest%20version.pdf)

Following is my code snippet:

```
PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
PrintService prsvc = getPrinterServiceByName(PrinterName);
printJob.setPrintService(prsvc);

PDDocument pdfdoc = PDDocument.load(PdfFile);
printJob.setPageable(new PDPageable(pdfdoc, printJob));

printJob.print();
pdfdoc.close();
```

Now I have been updated with the latest PDFBox 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT version,
and use `PDFPrinter` constructor to print PDF.And add `ImageableArea` to define paper imageable area using custom format.But issue still existed. See below:

```
PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
PrintService prsvc = getPrinterServiceByName(PrinterName);
printJob.setPrintService(prsvc);

PDDocument  document = PDDocument.load(PdfFile);

Paper paper  = new Paper();
paper.setSize(1005.0,396.0);  //354.5 x 139.7 mm
paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, 1005.0, 396.0); //354.5 x 139.7 mm


//result 139.7 mm x 354.5 mm. Rotated 90 degrees
PDFPrinter printer = new PDFPrinter(document,printJob,Scaling.ACTUAL_SIZE,Orientation.PORTRAIT,paper,false,0);

//result 139.7 mm x 354.5 mm. Rotated 90 degrees and context inverted.
//PDFPrinter printer = new PDFPrinter(document,printJob,Scaling.ACTUAL_SIZE,Orientation.LANDSCAPE,paper,false,0); 

//same result with setting Orientation.LANDSCAPE
//PDFPrinter printer = new PDFPrinter(document,printJob,Scaling.ACTUAL_SIZE,Orientation.AUTO,paper,false,0); 

PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
job.setPageable(printer.getPageable());

printer.silentPrint();
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I assume `PDPageable` tries to optimize the print orientation depending on the PDF and paper formats. Have you tried to use the `org.apache.pdfbox.rendering` class `PDFPrinter` instead? It offers different constructors, some of them accepting an `Orientation` parameter. Be sure to update your PDFBox SNAPSHOT, though, as there has been some development this year.

Comment: mkl ist right; additionally, you're not using the latest version, PDPageable no longer exists. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23487991/ .

Comment: TKS,I have been updated with the latest version,but problem  still existed.

Comment: Your code doesn't work because printJob doesn't exist. I slightly corrected it and it does what I would expect, considering that you're doing portrait and scaling actual size.

Comment: Hi,Tilman. My code is work. Above code snippt is not complete, I have been updated it and also have beeen updated [printed PDF download link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33134610/testPrintPDF/printedPDF%20by%20latest%20version.pdf).

My question is that printed PDF does not what I would expect.I expect it size should be 
354 x 139 mm (same size as original example PDF) but result is 210 x 297 mm.

Comment: The size of a print-out depends very much on the printer itself. Your printer seems to support A4 paper only.

Comment: I used virtual [Bullzip PDF Printer](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php) to print PDF and configure its page size to A3 paper,but printed PDF still get incorrect size.

Comment: Please look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2033 to see whether the advice at the end helps you.

Comment: @Tilman thank for your assistance.
Now I have added `ImageableArea` to define paper imageable area using custom format.But issue still existed. See above upated question.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds weird, but could you try to print from Acrobat Reader into your "virtual printer"? Because I tried what you did with PDFCreator and always got A4 pdfs, even if I configured A0.

Comment: @Tilman Could you tell me how to your configuration step?
Because it is work for me that printed form Acrobat Reader to virtual PDFCreator & Bullzip PDF Printer.
I manually configured with paper A3 size, actual size, and landscape orientation.
And result printed PDF can got it.
See following:

Comment: [printedPDF(by PDFCreater,landscape,A3).pdf](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33134610/testPrintPDF/printedPDF%28by%20PDFCreater%2Clandscape%2CA3%29.pdf)

[printedPDF(by Bullzip PDF Printer,landscape,A3).pdf](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33134610/testPrintPDF/printedPDF%28by%20Bullzip%20PDF%20Printer%2Clandscape%2CA3%29.pdf)

Comment: I tried with a different software (CIB pdf brewer) and it isn't rotated. I traced through PDFBox (when still using PDFCreator) and there it prints horizontally, so the rotation must have been done in PDF Creator (an older version). I tried with A0 in the properties in the CIB print dialog and the result had the correct size. (I didn't use silent print because I don't want to mess with my system by permanently configuring a size) See the file here: http://home.snafu.de/tilman/tmp/JavaPrinting.pdf

Comment: @Tilman Seems like printred paper direction of rotation depends on printer determines.Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(document));
job.print();
```

see with PDFBox 2.0.0:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2844